Open apps show icons on dock but will not display on desktop
Using Ubuntu 24 Noble on a Dell Latitude 5550. First noticed this problem when attempting to open Timeshift in a Gui. After entering password the app icon appeared on the dock but gui will not display on desktop. Right click icon and gui is there in context menu but can only be closed. Same issue with Software Updater: open the app and it appears on desktop as it searches for updates. If there are updates, the gui vanishes. I can select "apply all updates" by right clicking the icon on the dock, but have no idea what the updates are.
Then, while tiling a Libreoffice document, the window vanished off the right edge of the desktop. Now, when opening a Libreoffice document the icon appears on the dock but the gui is nowhere to be found.
I tried sudo apt update and then sudo apt upgrade and that allowed Timeshift's gui to appear on the desktop again--one time-- but then the system reverted to not showing app windows for some open apps again. I appreciate any clear and helpful answers.

When I mentioned this problem to a friend she said, "It sounds like the system thinks there is another monitor." And sure enough, when I looked in settings under "display" there was an additional monitor called "unknown 23 inch." Clicking on this opened an option to disable it, and when this was done the problem went away.
How this "phantom monitor" was enabled is another issue (because I've never used an external monitor with this laptop), but I suspect it happened when I plugged some external speakers into the laptop--strange as that sounds.

Thanks, I was facing the same problem! I saw an Unknown 35" phantom monitor. But I have used external monitors withe this Laptop. But the last time the monitor was plugged was about a month ago. This issue is something new.
